# How to make a nested view take the full width and height of the screen in react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, styling

Here's an image to explain the nesting of a view[image]

There's some `containerView` for a component, inside it can be a series of nested Views, and inside `someChildView`, we have a `cardView`. When someone presses the card view, I would like for it to animate to full width and height of the containerView.

I can't set it to absolute, as it seems to only reach the bounds of it's parent view. I would like to have a toggle that alters the cardView from what it looks like in the image, to full screen.

Here's an example of a simplified render function for some arbitrary component:

```
<containerView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <someChildView style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
    <cardView style={this.widthAndHeightToggle()} />
    <cardView style={this.widthAndHeightToggle()} />
  </someChildView>
</containerView>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

A good approach is to have another cardView inside of containerView and use it when toggled.

```
<containerView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Modal>
    <cardViewToggled />
  </Modal>
  <someChildView style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
    <cardView style={this.widthAndHeightToggle()} />
    <cardView style={this.widthAndHeightToggle()} />
  </someChildView>
</containerView>
```

Show the cardView within the Modal whenever you want to show it as full view. The Modal will cover the entire screen.

Comment: This would simulate a Modal to appear, I don't want that. I want to have the specific cardView object expand it's top, left, right, bottom to be 0 and position absolute, which would be absolute to containerView. so that I can animate the specific card to full screen, and back to it's original location.

Comment: Modal is not bad in React Native. It is full screen. And it has an animation to go along with it.